# Why is it necessary to load every argument onto the stack in CIL method?

Tags: .net, stack, cil, arguments, ilgenerator

in my application I need to dynamically create a type that contains multiple properties. I am aware that in cases such as this, one has to generate an CIL for both getter and setter methods of a property by using an ILGenerator.

More by a trial and error than anything else, I've finally arrived to the following code that generates a setter method for me:

```
MethodBuilder setMethod = customTypeBuilder.DefineMethod(propertyName + "_set", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, null, new Type[] {propertyType});
ILGenerator setIlGenerator = setMethod.GetILGenerator();
setIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
setIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
setIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, backingField);
setIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

The code works well enough, but there is one thing I don't understand about it. **Why is it necessary to call the 'Ldarg_0' instruction?**

I know that it refers to the implicit first argument of the method, the "this" reference, so the actual value for the setter is stored in the second argument. I thought that it should be sufficient to call the Ldarg_1 instruction only, which would push the second argument to the stack (in the end, in the setter, I have no need of examining the "this" reference so I don't need to do anything with it), but this results in the TargetInvocationException being thrown when I attempt to set the value of the property.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you didn't push the "this" value onto the stack, how would `Stfld` know which object's field to change? You could be trying to write a setter like this:

```
public int Bizarre
{
    set { otherObject.Field = value; }
}
```

Basically, `Stfld` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stfld.aspx) to need two values on the stack: one for the "target" of the new value, and one for the value itself. Admittedly the stack transition diagram in ECMA 335 is clearer:

```
…, obj, value => …,
```

In other words: "stfld will pop the top two elements off the stack".

Comment: Ah, of course! Now I almost feel ashamed that I asked a question like that. I've never wrote a line of code in CIL or assembler before, so it's sometimes quite hard to get my head around some of CIL's concepts. But now, it seems really simple. 

Thank you very much!